# How do you remove data from an array in c#

Tags: c#

I have a 2 dimensional array that holds values for student info. I have 3 constants to store them.
STUDENT_NAME, STUDENT_ID, MAJOR.

names is my array.

```
       names[Row,STUDENT_NAME] = txtStudentName.Text;
        names[Row, STUDENT_ID] = txtStdBox.Text;
        names[Row, MAJOR] = txtMJbox.Text;
```

And I use a text box to add data into a list box.
So I can delete a selected value in the list box, by clicking the delete button.
So how can i delete data from the array and the list box at the same time.

Comment: Why would you use a multi-dimensional string array rather than creating a separate class (`Student`) to encapsulate this, and then use a `List<Student>` to store the students?

Comment: I agree with Jon Skeet.  Also, if you're developing UI using .NET (whether WPF or WinForms) you should be using databinding, so the data would only exist in one collection.  What UI framework are you using?

Comment: To directly answer the question though, I think `names[Row, Student_NAME] = null;` should do.

Answer (score 3):

1) Create a student class

```
public class Student
{
    String StudentName {get;set;}
    Int32 StudentId {get;set;}
    String Major {get;set;}
}
```

2) Create A Student List

```
List<Student> StudentList = new List<Student>();
```

3) Edited : Add Students Into Listbox Using Foreach

```
MyListBox.Items.Clear(); 
foreach (Student StudentObj in List<Student>) 
{
    MyListBox.Items.Add(StudentObj.StudentName); 
}
```

4) Delete Student

```
StudentList.RemoveAt(MyListBox.SelectedIndex);
```

Comment: I seriously wouldn't count on the indexes *always* being the same as some sort of faux two-way databinding...

Comment: So is that how I would remove data from my array and from the list box at the same time?